# (postgres) Different types of data having own limits on different columns

Tags: postgresql

I have a CTE that i want to grab data from, but i want different types of data with the same limit from the same CTE according to different rules.

Example: fruit_cte -> (id::integer, name::text, q1::boolean, q2::boolean)

I could do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 1 as query_num, * FROM fruit_cte WHERE q1 ORDER BY name LIMIT 100) as ABC
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 2 as query_num, * FROM fruit_cte WHERE q2 ORDER BY name LIMIT 100) as ABC
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM (SELECT -1 as query_num, * FROM fruit_cte WHERE NOT q1 AND NOT q2 ORDER BY name LIMIT 100) as ABC
```

But this is very costly and would be nice to tie this up into 1 select. Is this even possible?

The last select is a nice to have to get data that doesn't meet the requirements but possible to go without.

PG version 11+

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get it all without the CTE, by using [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-window.html) instead.

```sql
SELECT type, id, name, q1, q2
FROM (
  SELECT
    CASE WHEN q1 THEN 1 WHEN q2 THEN 2 ELSE -1 END  AS type,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
      PARTITION BY CASE WHEN q1 THEN 1 WHEN q2 THEN 2 ELSE -1 END
      ORDER BY NAME
    )                                               AS row_number,
    id,
    name,
    q1,
    q2
  FROM ...
)
WHERE row_number <= 100
```

The `row_number()` will count, sorted by `name`, and keep a separate tally for every `type`

Comment: you are awesome